# How can I add ra_neon to svn on OSX

Tags: macos, svn

I have the latest version on svn but it is without ra_neon. I need to access the svn repository by the https protocol. Is there a way to add the ra_neon module?

This is an OSX 10.8.4 computer.

```
svn --version

svn, version 1.7.8 (r1419691)
   compiled Feb  8 2013, 14:56:55

Copyright (C) 2012 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see (link removed)

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

Most posts out there say that you need to compile the SVN source and add the neon module this way. I noticed that there was an SVN version that I could update too. So I tried this route.

Here is the SVN update URL: https://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release
Here is the URL for neon: http://www.webdav.org/neon/

Then I tried to configure it with neon support with this command:
./configure --with-neon=/path_to_neon/neon-0.29.6/

After make and make install completed I looked to see if it was installed. To my horror SVN was updated but without neon module installed.

```
svn --version

svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled May 13 2013, 10:08:54

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see  (link removed)

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

**Again, Does anyone know how to just install or enable the ra_neon module?**

Comment: well, I noticed that there is a newer version of SVN out there. So I downloaded it and installed it with the ra_neon argument. And added the steps to the issue above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to install just the module without compiling it against the source for subversion, so I think you're best bet is to download the subversion source (and neon) and do an install from source.

Here is the sequence that worked for me:

1. download neon
2. compile and install neon
3. download, compile, install subversion

```
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ cd neon-0.29.6
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ ./configure --help
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ ./configure --with-ssl=openssl
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ make
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ sudo make install
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ cd ../subversion-1.7.9
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ ./configure --with-neon=/usr/local --with-openssl --prefix=/usr
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ make
    Right-Effort:lmg42$ sudo make install

    Right-Effort:lmg42$ svn --version
    svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
       compiled May 30 2013, 12:41:24

    Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
    This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
    file for more information.
    Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

    The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

    * ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
      - handles 'http' scheme
      - handles 'https' scheme
    * ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
      - with Cyrus SASL authentication
      - handles 'svn' scheme
    * ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
      - handles 'file' scheme
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This is what I have been trying. I'll try again just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is 10.2.8? You mean you're on Jaguar? That was released over a decade ago about the a year after Windows XP was released. I don't think anyone supports it any more. Jaguar should have come with a version of Subversion (1.4 or 1.5) that includes neon and Apache with all the bells and whistles you need for Subversion.

10.2.8 is no longer supported. I checked the various binaries, but the earliest supported version with prebuilt binaries is Leopard (10.5.x). You're still running on a PowerPC and not Intel.

If there was a mistake, and your OS isn't that old, you can go to [SVN Binaries](http://svnbinaries.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?expandFolder=164&folderID=0) on CollabNet and see what they have.

Otherwise, you should head down to [Macports](https://www.macports.org) and see what they have.

Comment: It is  OSX 10.8.4, sorry I have no idea what happened there.